# Upload file with xsl extension only

Tags: angularjs, html, file-upload

I need a way to allow me browse the files with xsl extensions only , I'm using angular for client side scripting , thus if there's noway to do it with html5 is there's a way in angular?

```js
 <input fileread="XSLFileUpload.file" type="file" name="datafile" accept=".xsl" class="fileup" ng-  required="true"/>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. You really need to add more detail on what you have tried.

Comment: I reviewed it,please check